# recursive grep search for special charactes (C++ operators) in a file

Tags: shell, command-line, grep

I am trying to do a recursive search in a directory, looking for  instances where the following sequence of characters occur in my code files:

**-=**

I am using the following command at the CLI:

```
grep -rn -= --include=*.hpp .
```

I get the following error message:

```
grep: invalid option -- '='
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

Unfortunately, the help dosen't help much in addressing my question (or at least, I can't see how it addresses my problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
grep -rn --include=*.hpp -- -= .
```

The issue is that `-=` is interpreted as a command-line option. Use `--` to signify end of command-line options, so the `-=` is interpreted as a pattern instead.

Comment: Yes that works. I will accept your answer as soon as I am allowed to (in about 5 mins)

Comment: Thanks! Also note that doomster is right, if there are any `.hpp` files in the directory you run this from, you'll probably want to escape that `*` to avoid the shell globbing it before `grep` even sees it. E.g. `--include='*.hpp'`.

Comment: The conventional solution is `grep -rne -= --include=*.hpp .` -- the `-e` option allows you to pass in a regex which starts with a dash.

Answer (score 1):

`grep -r -- -= .` perhaps? The `--` separates the options (starting with -) from the rest of the commandline. BTW: You might have to hide the asterisk from your shell, i.e. use `--include=\*.hpp`